# Base class with variadic template constructor wont copy-construct from derived class

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, variadic

When i compile this code with visual studio 2013 i get an error:

```
error C2664: 'std::array<int,10>::array(const std::array<int,10> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'const std::array<int,10> &'
```

I thought that any derived class could be staticaly cast (sliced) to its base class always, why doesn't this work here?

And I thought that it would work even without a explicit cast?

```
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    std::array<T, 10> data;
    template <typename... Z>
    A(Z... ts) : data({ ts... }) { }
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    template <typename... Z>
    B(Z... ts) : A<T>({ ts... }) { }
};

int main()
{
    B<int> w(1,4,3);
    A<int> g(w); //cant construct from derived class
    A<int> h(static_vast< A<int> >(w)); //not even with cast

    A<int> j(4,5);
    A<int> t(j);  //regular copy constructor works

    B<int> p(t); //works, can construct derived from base
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem I can see is that your compiler could interpret the argument of the constructor as one of the types in `Z` rather than calling the copy constructor.

Comment: Yes I guess that could be happening, but I've tried constructing a derived B using A (last line in main), and it works.. Why does the opposite assume it to be one of the types in Z?

Comment: There is a typo and a bug in your cast: `static_cast< A<int>& >(w)` will work. If you use `static_cast< A<int> >(w)`, this will construct an `A<int>` from `w` just like `A<int> g(w);`.

Comment: `A<int> g(w); //cant construct from derived class` That's because your constructor template is too greedy. The compiler-generated copy constructor that would perform the slicing has the signature `A(A const&)`. Binding a `B<int>` to a `A<int> const&` is ranked as a Derived-to-Base conversion, which is considered a worse conversion than the exact match produced by the constructor template specialization `A(B<int>)`.

Comment: @dyp, you are right static_cast< A<int>& >(w) works. But in the case of a Base-to-Derived conversion, i.e. B<int> p(t);, means that a exact match is inferior to a Base-to-Derived conversion? Shouldn't an exact match always be preferable?

Comment: I think what happens with `B<int> p(t);` is that the constructor template is instantiated to `B::B(A<int> p)` so the `A<T>({ ts... })` in the member-initializer-list becomes `A<T>({ p })`. Since a type cannot be deduced for `{ p }` (because of the `{}`), the constructor template of `A` is not viable, and the move-constructor is used instead. Note that this creates another temporary copy which binds to the `&&` of the move constructor.